# How do you select some elements but exclude others with the same partial class with XPath?

Tags: xpath, lxml

With a general XPath (or with specific functions of lxml in python), how do you select a set of elements that have a set of tags like this?

```
<div class="cl1 a">
<div class="cl1 b">
```

but not

```
<div class="cl1">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the XPath `//div[starts-with(@class,"cl1 ")]`; note the space after `cl1`. For example,

```
In [20]: import lxml.html as LH
In [21]: doc = LH.parse('data.html')
In [24]: doc.xpath('//div[starts-with(@class,"cl1 ")]')
Out[24]: [<Element div at 0x7f0568c68100>, <Element div at 0x7f0568c68158>]

In [25]: [LH.tostring(elt) for elt in doc.xpath('//div[starts-with(@class,"cl1 ")]')]
Out[25]: ['<div class="cl1 a"></div>\n', '<div class="cl1 b"></div>\n']
```